# What does 手伝いのしているのですか mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence

I find this in a manga I understand that is "help doing" but have some questions

1. している is the verb します? If is, in what form are?
2. the か at the end of the sentence means that is a question?
3. why use です at the end of the sentences?

Comment: There seems to be a typo. Isn't it 手伝い**を**?

Comment: @naruto you are right I think It should be を but in the manga say の do you have some idea why?

Comment: I don't know... Possibly a longer context in Japanese might help, but usually it should be a simple typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. している is the verb します? If is, in what form are?

している means it is progressive.

> 2. the か at the end of the sentence means that is a question?

Yes. か indicates an interrogative sentence.

> 3. why use です at the end of the sentences?

です in a sentence makes it polite or formal. ですか in the sentence means you are asking a question in a polite way.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer but with the comment of @naruto I have one more question do you have idea about why use の instead of を?